# How do I apply chow test/Fstats in R to detect structural change

Tags: r, statistics

I have got monthly data from 1993 to 2015, and would like to detect structural change in my data.

I know there is a package "strucchange", that can compute Fstats to determine the statistical significance between the different points of the data, but I am not sure what is the way to go about it.

From the different statistical significance values, I will then take the point where it has highest value, and determine it as my break point, and use my more recent observation to do forecasting.

For example, this is some of my data set,

```
       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct   Nov   Dec
2006  7.55  7.63  7.62  7.50  7.47  7.53  7.55  7.47  7.65  7.72  7.78  7.81
2007  7.71  7.67  7.85  7.82  7.91  7.91  8.00  7.82  7.90  7.93  7.99  7.93
2008  8.46  8.48  9.03  9.43 11.58 12.19 12.23 11.98 12.26 12.31 12.13 11.99
2009 11.51 11.75 11.87 11.91 11.87 11.69 11.66 11.23 11.37 11.71 11.88 11.93
2010 11.99 11.84 12.33 12.55 12.58 12.67 12.57 12.35 12.30 12.67 12.71 12.63
2011 12.60 12.41 12.68 12.48 12.50 12.30 12.39 12.16 12.38 12.36 12.52 12.63
```

I want to find significant difference between the first "How many" values and the most recent "how many" values, then extract the most recent values out.

How do I do this in R?

I want to try running Fstats, but it give me error message as well, as I am not sure how it works.

**Code:**

```
fs <- Fstats(product, from = c(1993, 1), to = c(2015,5))
```

**Error:**

> Error in formula$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I am unsure what to key in the "formula" of Fstats to get what I want, so I just put in the data instead. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Regarding your data, is it a time series or data.frame or matrix?

Comment: You need to have a formula as per  `?Fstats` `Fstats(formula, from = 0.15, to = NULL, data = list(), vcov. = NULL)`  Check the first example `fs.nile <- Fstats(Nile ~ 1)`  Or the second example which is more like your data, `UKDriverDeaths`

Comment: I understand that I need a formula, but I am not sure what do I set as the formula, from the examples given in strucchange package, the formula are either the data~(lag values or sum of some variable). I am unsure do I just put a lag of my data, then just data~lag(data)? What is the purpose in doing so?

Answer (score 1):

For detecting structural *change*, there needs to be a notion of what is *stability*. This is necessary because there are many variations that are regular in some way, e.g., you could have a stationary time series with constant mean and variance. Or you could have a stable seasonal pattern. Or a stable drift in a random walk. Or some stable autoregressive pattern etc.

In case of the `strucchange` package you need to define a parametric model that describes the (hypothesized) stable behavior of the time series. Most functions in `strucchange` (specifically `Fstats()`) therefore expect you to specify the `formula` for a linear regression model.

- Zeileis A, Leisch F, Hornik K, Kleiber C (2002).
  "strucchange: An R Package for Testing for Structural Change in Linear Regression Models."
  *Journal of Statistical Software*, **7**(2), 1-38.
  URL http://www.jstatsoft.org/v07/i02/
- Zeileis A, Kleiber C, Krämer W, Hornik K (2003).
  "Testing and Dating of Structural Changes in Practice."
  *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, **44**, 109-123.

But there are also functions (specifically `gefp()`) that can deal with general parametric models associated with a score functions, see:

- Zeileis A (2006).
  "Implementing a Class of Structural Change Tests: An Econometric Computing Approach."
  *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, **50**, 2987-3008.

In case of your data, I'm not sure what a suitable model would be. The series does not seem to be stationary, even when accounting for the biggest jumps. The first differences seem to indicate some changes in drift and variance...but this is just eyeballing and no formal assessment.

```
x <- ts(c(7.55, 7.63, 7.62, 7.5, 7.47, 7.53, 7.55, 7.47, 7.65, 7.72, 
  7.78, 7.81, 7.71, 7.67, 7.85, 7.82, 7.91, 7.91, 8, 7.82, 7.9, 
  7.93, 7.99, 7.93, 8.46, 8.48, 9.03, 9.43, 11.58, 12.19, 12.23, 
  11.98, 12.26, 12.31, 12.13, 11.99, 11.51, 11.75, 11.87, 11.91, 
  11.87, 11.69, 11.66, 11.23, 11.37, 11.71, 11.88, 11.93, 11.99, 
  11.84, 12.33, 12.55, 12.58, 12.67, 12.57, 12.35, 12.3, 12.67, 
  12.71, 12.63, 12.6, 12.41, 12.68, 12.48, 12.5, 12.3, 12.39, 12.16, 
  12.38, 12.36, 12.52, 12.63), start = 2006, freq = 12)
plot(x)
plot(diff(x))
```

[image: ts]

Answer (score 0):

NarayanPopp2010 test has more stat'l power than ZA1992, LS2003, and others (See N2013 paper for comparisons). 
I converted the Gauss code of Popp to R, and the following is the output for your data: (currently, I have coded it for TR-locale).

```
x <- c(7.55, 7.63, 7.62, 7.5, 7.47, 7.53, 7.55, 7.47, 7.65, 7.72, 7.78, 7.81, 7.71, 7.67, 7.85, 7.82, 7.91, 7.91, 8, 7.82, 7.9, 7.93, 7.99, 7.93, 8.46, 8.48, 9.03, 9.43, 11.58, 12.19, 12.23, 11.98, 12.26, 12.31, 12.13, 11.99, 11.51, 11.75, 11.87, 11.91, 11.87, 11.69, 11.66, 11.23, 11.37, 11.71, 11.88, 11.93, 11.99, 11.84, 12.33, 12.55, 12.58, 12.67, 12.57, 12.35, 12.3, 12.67, 12.71, 12.63, 12.6, 12.41, 12.68, 12.48, 12.5, 12.3, 12.39, 12.16, 12.38, 12.36, 12.52, 12.63)

narayanpopp(x)
## Narayan-Popp IKI YAPISAL KIRILMALI DURAGANDISILIK SINAMASI ## 
Ornek (baslangic ani - son an):1 - 72 
Gozlem sayisi: 72 ; Enbuyuk gecikme: 5 ; Budama carpani: 0.2 
Yapisal kirilma ani tabani, etkili budamacarpani:15 : 15 ; 0.208333333333333 
Yapisal kirilma ani tavani, etkili (1-budamacarpani):57 : 57 ; 0.791666666666667 
V0: (iki yapisal kirilmayla) seri duragandisi; V1:(iki yapisal kirilmayla) seri duragan 
sinamaistatistigi>karardegeri => V0 'i koru; sinamaistatistigi<karardegeri => V1 'i koru 
*********************************************************************** 
 *-----M0 KALIBININ SONUCLARI:-----* 
[1] "Ilk yapisal kirilma ani:26 26 8.48 0.361111111111111"
[1] "Ikinci yapisal kirilma ani:28 28 9.43 0.388888888888889"
[1] "fi=ro-1 :-0.163160512806634"
[1] "t degeri:-2.29771524783461"
[1] "Eniyi gecikme:1"
[1] "Degisme (varyans):0.0363825152276192"
............Katsayi...t-istatistigi... 
                   x         x
y1g       -0.1631605 -2.297715
kesme      1.3160065  2.362884
kukla1.1g  0.4741074  2.190526
kukla2.1g  0.2079939  0.700877
dtb1       0.6145683  3.057550
dtb2       1.8379621  6.770421
1          0.1513192  2.084880
 *-----M1 KALIBININ (iki yapisal kirilma: kesmede yk + kesmede yk) SONUCLARI:-----* 
[1] "Ilk yapisal kirilma ani:26 26 8.48 0.361111111111111"
[1] "Ikinci yapisal kirilma ani:28 28 9.43 0.388888888888889"
[1] "fi=ro-1: -0.37110021277495"
[1] "t degeri:-3.86603074072343"
Karar degerleri(%1,%5,%10):[1] -4.958 -4.316 -3.980
[1] "Eniyi gecikme:4"
[1] "Degisme (varyans):0.0314227239677204"
............Katsayi...t-istatistigi... 
                    x          x
y1g       -0.37110021 -3.8660307
kesme      2.76323682  3.8831542
kukla1.1g  0.60556752  2.9438927
kukla2.1g  0.60593575  1.9011479
dtb1       0.59763359  3.1380696
dtb2       1.75811366  6.6692227
zaman      0.01042009  3.1228153
1          0.23044610  3.1567308
2          0.06923344  0.9059798
3         -0.05159104 -0.6789619
4          0.17197982  2.2875677
 *-----M2 KALIBININ (iki yapisal kirilma: kesmede yk + egimde yk) SONUCLARI:-----* 
[1] "Ilk yapisal kirilma ani:28 28 9.43 0.388888888888889"
[1] "Ikinci yapisal kirilma ani:50 50 11.84 0.694444444444444"
[1] "fi=ro-1: -0.369017381997517"
[1] "t degeri:-3.2470432795371"
Karar degerleri(%1,%5,%10):[1] -5.576 -4.937 -4.596
[1] "Eniyi gecikme:1"
[1] "Degisme (varyans):0.0339671359124701"
............Katsayi...t-istatistigi... 
              izdusum1 tistatistik1
y1g       -0.369017382   -3.2470433
kesme      2.502710805    3.0577926
kukla1.1g  1.122424369    2.5998260
kukla2.1g  0.336741730    2.1075864
dtb1       2.244092825    9.6684805
dtb2       0.589019340    2.8927063
dt1.1g    -0.033995349   -2.8474147
dt2.1g     0.004277045    0.4448496
zaman      0.027863359    3.4816650
1          0.187482190    2.5306679
```

[image]

Hence, Ted, for your data;
M1 model indicates 2 str'l break locations: t=26th, 28th observations.
M2 model indicates 2 str'l break locations: t=28th, 50th observations.
Since superior M2 model overwrites M1's results, you see 2 red solid lines, 1 dashed black line. M1's 28th was overwritten by M2's 28th.